# Не сбрасываемый счётчик

Tags: javascript

Прошу подсказать, где можно почитать или как реализовать.
Суть задачи: Есть некое событие, где приходит ФИО сотрудника или не приходит и в случае, если не приходит, то я указываю NoName_(число: 0,1,2,3 и т.д.), но если в рамках работы скрипта происходит, что ФИО я получаю, потом нет и записываю в БД, как NoName_0, потом эта ситуация повторяется, то у меня снова NoName_0...
Существует ли возможность, как-то держать в буфере (как вариант) последнее число и к нему уже прибавлять +1?

```
    var i = 0;
function checkfio(e) {
    wm_fio = e.match;
    wm_temp = e.temp;
    Log.info(e.match, e.temp)
    if (wm_fio == "") {
        wm_fio = "Noname" + "_" + i++;
        Log.info("ФИО не передано");
    } else {
        Log.info(wm_fio);
    }
    insert(wm_fio, wm_temp);
}
```

Comment: Да, существует. Вариантов масса. Конкретизируйте вопрос?

Comment: Скрипт постоянно работает, но может быть ситуация, что он может быть отключен для проведения каких либо работ на сервере (перезагрузка и т.д.), где он работает. И именно по этому и возник вопрос, как реализовать "память" в скрипте, какой последний номер (++i) он присвоил переменной wm_fio = "Noname" + "_" + i++. 
Я могу сам почитать и постараться его реализовать, но не знаю, как правильно задать вопрос в гугле или что почитать. У меня есть мысль, чтоб он записывал в файл номер и при вызове, считывал последний номер в файле и делал +1.

Comment: Если у вас сервер и где-то рядом БД с сотрудниками - разумнее хранить там. Хотя тогда вопрос, почему бы это на БД не сгрузить - пускай бы вы ФИО сохраняли пустое, а БД сама себе генерила имя и поддерживала нужные счетчики.